# spring app not finding property on object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an object `calendar` of type `AppointmentCalendar`.  In a jsp called `calendar.jsp`, I call one of `calendar`'s properties as `calendar.day`.  But I am getting an error saying:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 9): Field or property 'day' cannot be found on object of type
```

Can anyone show me how to resolve this?

Here is the part of `calendar.jsp` which refers to the `day` property:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appointmentDay" class="prepend-6 span-4 alt">
        <spring:eval expression="calendar.day" />
    </div>
    <div id="appointmentNavigation" class="span-3 append-11 last alt">
        <c:url var="previousLink" value="/calendar">
            <c:param name="day" value="${calendar.previousDay}" />
        </c:url>
        <a href="${previousLink}">Previous</a>
        <c:url var="nextLink" value="/calendar">
            <c:param name="day" value="${calendar.nextDay}" />
        </c:url>
        <a href="${nextLink}">Next</a>  
    </div>
    <div id="dayPicker" class="span-6"></div>
    ... other irrelevant code
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of `EncounterController` which manages the `/calendar` url pattern:

```
@RequestMapping("/calendar")
public String showCalendar(Model model) {
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
    System.out.println("------------------------ in controller, day of month is:  "+today.getDayOfMonth());
    AppointmentCalendar calendar = new AppointmentCalendar(today); // Or whatever you do to create it
    model.addAttribute("calendar", calendar);
    return "appointments/calendar";
}
```

Here is AppointmentCalendar :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

public class AppointmentCalendar {
    @DateTimeFormat(style="F-")
    private LocalDate day;

    private List<Provider> providers;

    private List<Encounter> encounters; 

    public AppointmentCalendar(LocalDate day) {
        this.day = day;
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::: in AppointmentCalendar constructor, dayOfMonth is: "+day.getDayOfMonth());
    }

    public void setProviders(List<Provider> doctors) {
        this.providers = doctors;
        encounters = new ArrayList<Encounter>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {encounters.add(null);}
    }

    public void addEncounter(Encounter appointment) {
        int blockIndex = appointment.getDateTime().getHourOfDay() - 8;
        encounters.add(appointment);
    }

    public Long getDayMillis() {
        return day.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
    }

    public List<LocalTime> getBlocks() {
        List<LocalTime> blocks = new ArrayList<LocalTime>(9);
        LocalTime time = new LocalTime(8, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            blocks.add(time);
            time = time.plusMinutes(60);
        }
        return blocks;
    }

    public Long getBlockMillis(LocalTime block) {return day.toDateTime(block).getMillis();}

    public Date getStartOfDay() {return day.toDateTime(getBlocks().get(0)).toDate();}

    public Date getEndOfDay() {return day.toDateTime(getBlocks().get(8)).plusMillis(60).toDate();}

    // resource links

    public LocalDate getPreviousDay() {return day.minusDays(1);}

    public LocalDate getNextDay() {return day.plusDays(1);}

    // internal

    private List<Encounter> createEncounterList(int size) {
        List<Encounter> appointments = new ArrayList<Encounter>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {appointments.add(null);}
        return appointments;
    }
}
```

And here is the complete stack trace.  Notice that they `system.out.println()` output at the start shows that the methods are firing in the correct order, and that there is a value for the `day` property:

```
------------------------ in controller, day of month is:  6
:::::::::::::::::::::::::: in AppointmentCalendar constructor, dayOfMonth is: 6
Feb 6, 2014 1:34:21 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 6, 2014 1:34:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 9): Field or property 'day' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.AppointmentCalendar'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:216)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:43)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:346)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.doEndTag(EvalTag.java:126)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005feval_005f0(calendar_jsp.java:217)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspService(calendar_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Feb 6, 2014 1:34:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [KnowledgeManager] in context with path [/KnowledgeManager] threw exception [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 9): Field or property 'day' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.AppointmentCalendar'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 9): Field or property 'day' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.AppointmentCalendar'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:216)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:43)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:346)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.doEndTag(EvalTag.java:126)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005feval_005f0(calendar_jsp.java:217)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.appointments.calendar_jsp._jspService(calendar_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a public `getDay()` method to `AppointmentCalendar`.
Spring needs this getter to get the value of `day`.

In general when using Spring managed beans/classes
always add the respective getter and setter methods.

Comment: After getting the calendar functionality to run, I found that my patient management functionality does not run when I click on the link to load it in browser.  I am wondering if the new problem is related to how the calendar code is set up.  Do you mind taking a look at it and trying to resolve it?  Here is the link to the new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691629/hibernate-could-not-deserialize