# Spring App Error: EL1008E

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el, spring-dsl

I have been working on a Spring Integration project using Enterprise Integration Patterns to consume MQ messages, do some processing, then write them to another queue.

My problem appears very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614681/spring-app-not-finding-property-on-object) however the accepted answer hasn't fixed it for me.

After receiving a response from an external web service, my `@Cacheable` `@Component` class returns the body as an `ArrayList`. I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 1): Property or field 'valid' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public?
```

Here is, what I believe to be, the offending class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.curator.x.discovery.ServiceCache;
import org.apache.curator.x.discovery.ServiceInstance;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class DirectoryRepo {

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceCache<ServiceDetail> directoryServiceCache;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private ArrayList<X> response;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Cacheable(value = "X", unless = "!#result.valid")
    public ArrayList<X> checkForX(String a,
            String b, String c, String d) {

            try {

                //code omitted

                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.add("token", service.getPayload().getToken());

                ResponseEntity<X[]> responseEntity = restTemplate
                        .exchange(request, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(
                                headers), X[].class);


                if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.hasBody()) {

                    response = new ArrayList<X>(Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody()));
                    return response;
                } else {
                    logger.debug("received unexpected responseEntity: {}",
                            responseEntity);
                }
            } catch (RestClientException e) {
                logger.error("failed to get X - {}",
                        e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        throw new ServiceException(
                "failed to get X - Directory service unavailable");
    }

    public ArrayList<X> getResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }

    /**
     * Clears out all entries from the X cache.
     */
    @CacheEvict(value = "X", allEntries = true)
    public void clearXCache() {
        logger.trace("cacheManager:{}", cacheManager);
    }

}
```

As you can see I have tried setting a public getter method, but the exception still occurs:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 1): Property or field 'valid' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public
?
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:374) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:170) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OperatorNot.getValueInternal(OperatorNot.java:47) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OperatorNot.getValueInternal(OperatorNot.java:36) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.ExpressionEvaluator.unless(ExpressionEvaluator.java:123) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.canPutToCache(CacheAspectSupport.java:623) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELE
ASE]
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:675) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:361) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at somepackage.DirectoryRepo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7709589.checkForX(<generated>) ~[DirectoryRepo.class:?]
        at somepackage.DirectoryService.getX(DirectoryService.java:66) ~[DirectoryService.class:?]
```

context.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context displayName="appName" path="/appName" copyXML="true">

</Context>
```

Comment: Can you add a cache config xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear to me.

It's not clear what you are trying to do. The `#result` variable is a reference to the ...er... `result of calling the method` - i.e. the `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList` does not have a `isValid()` or `getValid()` method.

[The documentation about Conditional Caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition) describes what variables are available to you.

> As you can see I have tried setting a public getter method

I don't see any such thing.

You can do things like `result.size() > 0`, `a != 'foo'`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gary. Apologies if my question wasn't clear (first timer, here)!
This has resolved the issue after changing it to `#result.isEmpty()` instead. Someone else added the `unless` expression in so I didn't think to look there.

Comment: Hmm, no. "Cache the result, except if it is empty" is how I was reading it. If there are no results then the condition is `true` meaning the cache is vetoed.
Similar to the example in your link:
`unless="#result.hardback`
"Cache the result, except if it's hardback."

Comment: Doh - sorry yes; I was thrown by the original question.